# Whats wrong in my code . iam trying to calculate pi

Tags: dart

i dont know if iam using the right code to calculate pi please help me.

```
void main() {
  dynamic result=4 ;
  for (var i = 3; i <=15 ; i++) {
    var sign = -1;
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
      var t = 4*( 1/i) ;
      result=result+t*sign;
      sign = sign * -1;
    }
  }
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: What formula are you using?

Comment: 4(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doing everything right actually. Your sign was actually within loop so your variable sign was always negative. To reach value of Pi you would need a lot of iterations.

```
void main() {
  dynamic result=4 ;
     var sign = -1;
  for (var i = 3; i <=500 ; i++) {
 
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
      var t = 4*( 1/i) ;
      result=result+t*sign;
      sign = sign * -1;
    }
  }
  print(result);
}
```